# Creating a Loop Through 4 worksheets Paste not working

Tags: excel, vba

Hi guys I'm doing a course for Udemy and the lecturer unfortunately has not been the most responsive.

I have a workbook called QuarterlyReport and 5 sheets.

1. East Records
2. West Records
3. North Records
4. South Records
5. Yearly Report

My code formats the Worksheets 1-4 and then copy pastes the information to Yearly Report on the last unused row. **For some reason, the code is only pasting South Records. My goal is to copy every single sheet 1 - 4 and paste it onto the fifth sheet "YEARLY REPORT".**

```
Public Sub Finalreportloop()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1

    Do While i <= Worksheets.Count - 1
        Worksheets(i).Select

        AddHeaders
        FormatData
        AutoSum

        ' copy the current data
        Range("A1").Select
        Selection.CurrentRegion.Select

        Selection.Copy

        ' select the final report WS'
        Worksheets("yearly report").Select

        'find the empty cells

    LastRow = Sheets(i).Range("A" & Sheets(i).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


       'paste the new data in
        ActiveSheet.Paste

            i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

The Addheaders, FormatData and AutoSum are in reference to other Modules I've created. Thank you everyone!

Comment: `LastRow` uses the sheet you're copying from, not the one you're pasting into and then you don't even use it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The code determines the last row of the sheet that you are copying from, but you don't do anything with that information. Instead, it just pastes into the active sheet and overwrites the data posted in the last loop instance. Hence it looks as if it is only copying/pasting the last data set.

You need to find the last row in the Yearly sheet, then paste the data below that.

Answer (score 0):

You coudld try one of the methods below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsLastRow As Long, wsLastColumn As Long, yrLastRow As Long
    Dim rngCopy  As Range

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        If ws.Name <> "YEARLY REPORT" Then

            With ws
                'Method 1 - You can siply used range
'                .UsedRange.Copy

                'Method 2 - You can calculate LastColumn & LastRow and create the range
                wsLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row '<- Find last row of column A.
                wsLastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column '<- Find the last column of row 1.
                Set rngCopy = .Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(wsLastRow, wsLastColumn)) '<- Create the range to be copy.
                rngCopy.Copy

            End With

            With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("YEARLY REPORT")
                yrLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row '<- Find last row of column A.
                .Range("A" & yrLastRow + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End With

        End If

        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Next ws

End Sub
```